# Tables of eigenvalues for Hilbert newforms of level $\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: modular-forms

Bit of a naïve question but are there tables of Hecke eigenvalues for Hilbert newforms over say real quadratic fields (of parallel weight not necessarily equal to 2 and level $\Gamma_0(\mathfrak{p})$)?

For an explicit example (that I have been trying to get my hands on) let's say the field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$, the level is $\langle 7\rangle$ and the parallel weight is $4$.

I am aware that magma has packages to compute such things but they usually have limitations. If the level has an even number of prime ideals in it then magma uses definite quaternion algebras and has no problem. However for the odd case it has to use indefinite quaternion algebras and the package only seems to be handle parallel weight $2$ here (unless I am not giving it enough time).

I also tried the LMFDB but could only find specific examples for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{8})$.